# Clear ldap cache (apache directory studio)

Tags: windows-8, ldap, apacheds

I want to know how can I empty the ldap cache?
I am using apache directory studio and windows 8.

The problem is that when I try to add a user to my ldap directory `ou=users` it says that the entry already exist,and i know that the `ou=users` is empty.

Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't a refresh [F5/rightclick->reload] work?

Comment: when i do a refresh [F5/rightclick->reload], the ou=users is refreshed,but the entry is not there. When i try to insert it, it says that the entry already exist.

Comment: Having the same problem. Even uninstalled and installed the program but all the connections and everything are still intact...

Answer (score 0):

Do a "reload entry" on the schema (ou) at the highest level.

Comment: Still not working.